# Firebase storage, new image upload doesn't have a unique name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating an app using firebase and react.js. When I reload the app, only the very last image shows up, when instead all of them should be loaded on the first page. Here is my `handleUpload` function where the issue lies (Updated):

```
    const handleUpload = () => {
    //const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`);
    const randomId = doc(collection(db, "temp")).id;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${randomId}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);

    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
            //Progress function ... (shows the load bar)
            const progress = Math.round(
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            );
            setProgress(progress);
        },
        (error) => {
            //Error Function...
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.message);
        },
        async () => {
            //complete function
                const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
                const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
                    imageURL: url, 
                    caption: caption, 
                    username: username, 
                    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
                });

                console.log("THE APP HAS POSTED");
                setProgress(0);
                setCaption('');
                setImage(null);
                setUrl('');
            }
        )
            

    }
```

Here is my storage console after restarting and posting 2 photos from an iPhone: [image: Firebase storage console]

There should be 2 photos there, but only the latest one shows up, with the name `${image.name}`, which I don't understand because I have that line commented out.

Note: this issue only occurs when someone uploads on a phone since there are no file names on a phone, just a picture from a camera roll. Is there a way to fix this that anyone can think of?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase storage doesn't generate a random ID for new files. You must specify then file name while uploading it. You can use a package like [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or even Firestore to generate random IDs as shown below:

```
const randomId = doc(collection(db, "temp")).id
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${randomId}`);
```

Also make sure you add the file extension at the end of filename.

Are you trying to upload image with same name? In that case it'll overwrite the existing image with that name.

Comment: So when I am testing the app, I am uploading an image from an iPhone. Since there is no "filename" when you select an image from a camera roll, the image name is defaulting to "${image.name}" every time a new photo is uploaded, overwriting the last one. The solution you posted doesn't seem to fix the issue for some reason although it seems like the most sense to just generate a new name internally.

Comment: @JasonVitaleJr. generating a new ID using Firestore SDK isn't working? Can you update your question with the latest code you have?

Comment: assuming the solution you posted is correct, then no. I am new to firebase so it could be something as simple as not importing a function I need or something.

Comment: @JasonVitaleJr. can you try restarting dev server and trying once? If it still doesn't work please update the code in your question and also a screenshot from Firebase storage console would help to check what it's being uploaded as.

Comment: Just updated the question! Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks for helping!

Comment: @JasonVitaleJr. that looks valid. Can you try `console.log(storageRef.fullPath)` right after `const storageRef` and share what is outputs? Do restart the dev server after making any change.

Comment: So this is odd, nothing gets outputted. Even when I put `console.log("Hello World");` nothing gets outputted. The image still gets uploaded however so I know that it is reaching this part of the code. Restarting did not help.

Comment: I tried restarting with a new firebase project by changing my config file but the issue is still here, I am unsure why a unique ID is not being generated per image.

Comment: The issue is like you have `'images/${randomId}'` instead of backticks. Is this anywhere on Github by chance @JasonVitaleJr.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240732/discussion-between-jason-vitale-jr-and-dharmaraj).